# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am trying to do very simple thing with react router. But I keep on running into error - 'cannot read property 'push' of undefined'. This happens when i click on the test link.

```
import { Router, useRouterHistory, Route } from 'react-router';
import { createHashHistory } from 'history';
const appHistory = useRouterHistory(createHashHistory)({ queryKey: false });

ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(nav), document.getElementById('navComponent'));

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router history={appHistory}>
        <Route path="test" component={Test}/>
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('mainContainer'));
```

nav Component

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <ul>
               <li><Link to="/test"> Test </Link></li>
              </ul>    
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Test Component

```
render() {
        return (
            <div>
              Hello World!   
            </div>
        );
    };
```

Can someone please help me? been stuck here.

Update 1

the push is part of react-router

```
this.context.router.push(_location);
```

Package.json

```
{

  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^3.9.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^2.1.1",
    "gulp-util": "^3.0.7",
    "imports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.1.3",
    "jasmine": "2.3.2",
    "jasmine-core": "2.3.4",
    "jquery": "1.11.3",
    "moment": "2.10.6",
    "react": "0.14.2",
    "react-addons-test-utils": "0.14.2",
    "react-dom": "0.14.2",
    "redux": "3.0.3",
    "rewire": "2.5.1",
    "rewire-webpack": "1.0.1",
    "run-sequence": "^1.1.5",
    "style-loader": "0.12.4",
    "underscore": "1.8.3",
    "webpack-stream": "^3.1.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-router": "^2.0.0",
  }
}
```

Update 2 
Sorry for not being clear with my question, i have updated my question hope it make more sense now

Comment: provide the code including `push` pls...

Comment: Can you provide `package.json` info or what modules did you installed?

Comment: @iplus26  please see updated question

Comment: Try by running `npm install history@1.17.0 --save`

Comment: @mitogh sorry, but it does not work. react-router does depends upon history

Answer (score 0):

It works like following. Please compare your solution. Basically topmost route should have path as "/" for children "/" not required

```
<Router history={appHistory}>
        <Route path="/" component={Main}>
            <Route path="test" component={Test}/>
            <Route path="*" component={Test}/>
        </Route>
</Router>

const Main = ({children, history}) => {
return (
<div>
<nav>
        <div history={history}/>
      </nav>
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
</div>
 )
}
```